# Getting the new Squeak 5 to run on 64 bit Linux

Tags: linux, 64-bit, squeak

In short: how do I get Squeak 5 to run on x64 Linux?
I dont care whether the executable is 32 or 64 bit as long as it runs and opens the Squeak 5 image.

---

Here is what I tried:

When I try to run the executables from the Squeak 5 package i get: `Running 32-bit Squeak on a 64-bit System. install-libs32 may install them` - tried that. Wasn't found.

Then I went looking for a 64 bit executable. There are some from Squeak 4 but they can't open Squeak 5 images.

Looking through the Squeak 5 package:

The shell scripts `squeak.sh` in both these directories:

- Squeak-5.0-All-in-One/
- Squeak-5.0-All-in-One/Squeak-5.0-All-in-One.app/Contents/LinuxAndWindows/

Both return this error:

`/usr/bin/ldd didn't produce any output and the system is 64 bit.  You may need to (re)install the 32-bit libraries.`

There are also misleading files named `squeak` (no .sh) in these directories:

- Squeak-5.0-All-in-One/Squeak-5.0-All-in-One.app/Contents/LinuxAndWindows/Linux-i686
- Squeak-5.0-All-in-One/Squeak-5.0-All-in-One.app/Contents/LinuxAndWindows/Linux-i686/bin

They are not the executable, just more shell scripts.

There is another `squeak` file in:

- Squeak-5.0-All-in-One/Squeak-5.0-All-in-One.app/Contents/LinuxAndWindows/Linux-i686/lib/squeak/5.0-3397

Running `./squeak` misleadingly says `No such file or directory`. It is misleading because the file does exist, it is just a 32-bit exe.

`file squeak` tells me: `ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386`.

---

So how do I get it to run on 64-bit Linux? I could compile it myself but haven't tried assuming there are a lot of dependencies. Or has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already got all information you need:

> `You may need to (re)install the 32-bit libraries.`

Squeak 5 is currently 32bit only. Hence, you need 32bit libraries.
It cannot use your 64bit libraries.

You may need thes:e packages (I use Debian/Ubuntu names, CentOS/RH/SuSE should be similar):

- libc6:i386
- libuuid1:i386
- libkrb5-3:i386
- libk5crypto3:i386
- zlib1g:i386
- libcomerr2:i386
- libkrb5support0:i386
- libkeyutils1:i386
- libx11-6:i386
- libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
- libsm6:i386
- libssl1.0.0:i386

(note the `:i386` in the names)

Comment: Thanks for this. I installed them using apt, but I still get the error `Running 32-bit Squeak on a 64-bit System.` I then also ran `install-libs32` which installed a bunch more and made a reboot, still the same error.

Comment: can you run squeak.sh with `bash -x squeak.sh` and put the output on <pastebin.com>?

Comment: thank you for this. It showed me that the true error message was that it did not find a display. Then I tried to give it `-nodisplay -headless -nomixer`, but the .sh dont seem to forward it to the true executable (already complained about that in another question). I then called the exe directly, giving it those args and a squeak 5 image and it seems to work now, at least the programs are running. Cannot get a network connection to it yet but that might be a blocked port. Tomorrow I will upload an image that writes out a file so I can make sure it runs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome. Feel free to join squeak-dev at lists.squeakfoundation.org for more in-depth help and longer discussions

Comment: @future-people: have confirmed that this works (dont skip the parts we wrote in these comments)

Answer (score 2):

This works in 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04:

In the directory where you unzipped the
Squeak-5.0-All-in-One.zip
archive, and that contains the squeak.sh file,
put the following into a file named libs32.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
objdump -p ./Squeak-5.0-All-in-One.app/Contents/LinuxAndWindows/Linux-i686/lib/squeak/5.0-3397/*|
grep NEEDED|
awk '{print $2}'|
sort -u|
xargs dpkg -S|
awk '{print $1}'|
sort -u|
sed 's/:amd64:/:i386:/'|
sort -u|
sed 's/:$//'
```

Make that file executable:

```
chmod +x ./libs32.sh
```

Run it:

```
./libs32.sh
```

You will get a list of libraries that need to be installed.

Run

```
./lib32.sh | xargs sudo apt install
```

to see what would be installed.

Run

```
./lib32.sh | xargs sudo apt install -y
```

to install it.